# How to create a SQL view by consolidating a table grouped by the values of their columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, view

I don't know how to call exactly what I'm trying to do, I'm picking up an existing project, but their views are unalterable, so I'm attempting to regenerate them by updating their config, unfortunately the initial db is slimmed down into only having 3 columns

| customer | config_item | config_setting |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10000001 | url | http://localhost |
| 10000001 | db | http://localhost:5432 |
| 10000001 | queue | http://localhost |
| 10000002 | url | http://localhost |
| 10000002 | db | http://localhost:5432 |
| 10000002 | queue | http://localhost |

into a view

| customer_id | url | db | queue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10000001 | http://localhost | http://localhost:5432 | http://localhost |
| 10000002 | http://localhost | http://localhost:5432 | http://localhost |

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW customer_settings AS (
  SELECT m.id AS customer, m.is_active FROM
    customer_master m
  LEFT JOIN 
    customer_config c
    c.url = c.config_setting WHERE c.customer_id = m.id AND c.config_item = 'url'
    c.db = c.config_setting WHERE c.customer_id = m.id AND c.config_item = 'db'
    c.queue = c.config_setting WHERE c.customer_id = m.id AND c.config_item = 'queue'
);
```

I can get all of the necessary data through individual selects, but I don't know how to implement those into a view

```
select config_setting from customer_config where customer_id = 1000001 AND config_item = 'url';

select config_setting from customer_config where customer_id = 1000001 AND config_item = 'db';

select config_setting from customer_config where customer_id = 1000001 AND config_item = 'queue';
```

Comment: It's not exactly clear what you are asking ...

Answer (score 0):

`crosstab()` is typically fastest. Minimal form:

```sql
SELECT customer_id, url, db, queue
FROM   crosstab(
  'SELECT customer_id, config_item, config_setting
   FROM   customer_config
   ORDER  BY 1, 2'
   ) AS (customer_id int, db text, queue text, url text);
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=aca3bcd813b75f85153d5ff301cae284)*

Your question leaves room for interpretation. You may need to be more explicit, especially if rows can be missing in `customer_config`. See:

- [PostgreSQL Crosstab Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query/11751905#11751905)